# Limit number of profiles a free user can view?

Tags: php, sql, limit

Is there a way that will allow me to limit the amount of profiles a user can look at on my site per day. so for instance each user has an id 1, 2, 3 etc. and if the one user views 5 profiles all together in one day then it stops them viewing any more and redirects them to a sign up page to become a paid member where they can view unlimited profiles?

I'm quite new to php and sql but this is primarily what i am working in if there's a way to do it in that.

Thanks

Comment: Do not mind please. Being quite new user I would like to guide you rather than down-voting. Here you should ask only the problem where you are stuck technically. Users are not supposed to ask just guidance of designing their software.

You can easily Limit number of profiles a free user can view. You have a button/link to each profile where user clicks to check a profile. You have to make a check there. If you have written some code against that link/button. You can be helped to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your database create 1 table called user_views with 3 fields
id (auto increament), user_id (the user who is visiting), visited_user_id (the user id who is visited)..

At your user_details page which users see other user, at the start of your code set 1 function which will add that view to this table , if user has already visited this user it must ignore it and if user has make all allowed visits this function will redirect him ...

And the db table must be truncate each day at 00:00:00..

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple use of SESSION variables and a counting mechanism would suffice.

Comment: Plentyoffish.com employs this exact method you are looking for but via cookies. After you delete the cookies the user can view again 5 times. Session variables offer a little more control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Each time the user views a profile, store that information `(viewer, who they viewed, a time stamp)`.

Every time they go to view a profile, check how many profiles they have viewed today. If it's over the **limit**, `redirect them`.

There's other logic you may want to consider, for example, if they come back to the same profile 5 times, does it count each time?

Comment: ok cool thank you. and yea it would be 5 profiles all round so no going back to re-view a profile. is there any demo's or threads you might know of?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can limit them in viewing,

1. you can save it in database and every time they view each profile then save it into ur database, you can make a table,
   tbl_user_view
   field: user_id, view_count 

   every profile view make an update function wich 
   `UPDATE tble_user_view set view_count = view_count + 1 WHERE user_id = user_id`

and here's some twist, if the user viewed the same profile twice you need to record it as 1,
so save the id of the profile that they viewed in COOKIES or if you do not care on database load you can save it there.